# How can I assign select2 plugin to select element which has plugin options as json object at data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2, custom-data-attribute

I use many select2 plugin and I want to assign options and options values of plugin from related element's data attribute as like below;

**HTML**

```
<select data-plug="select2" data-plug-op='{"placeholder":"text1","containerCssClass":"maincss"}'>
    <option></option>
</select>

<select data-plug="select2" data-plug-op='{"placeholder":"text2","containerCssClass":"maincss2","dropdownCssClass":"dropdowncss"}'>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var slc = $('[data-plug="select2"]');

assignSelect(slc);

function assignSelect(selectElement) {

    selectElement.each(function(){

        var $this  = $(this),
            plugOp = $.parseJSON( $this.attr('data-plug-op') );

        /*-- --*/
        $.each(plugOp,function(k,v){

           $this.select2({
             k:v
           });

        });
        /*-- --*/

    });

}
```

I get options from related element's data attribute and parse it as JSON but I can't assign to plugin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably i've found a solution to your problem
In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/AWNLL/) the attribute data-plug-op of the two options is used to build the plugin select2 object.
Since in this case i don't knew maincss and maincss2 i used width and placeholder for differentiating the two options
the code seems to work the first options has a placeholder = "text1" and a width of 200
the second option has a placeholder="text2" and width=400
All jQuery code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.each($('[data-plug="select2"]'),function(index){
         obj={}
         var $this  = $(this),
            plugOp = $.parseJSON( $this.attr('data-plug-op') );

        for(prop in plugOp) {
            obj[prop]=plugOp[prop]
        }
        $('[data-plug="select2"]:eq('+index+')').select2( $.extend({}, obj))
    })

});
</script>
```

A more sintetic way to obtain the same result coul be [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/8P5z6/1/)
 where i use a bit of css to differentiate two options group

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.each($('[data-plug="select2"]'),function(index){
         var $this  = $(this)
         var plugOp = $.parseJSON( $this.attr('data-plug-op') );
        $('[data-plug="select2"]:eq('+index+')').select2(plugOp)
    })
});
</script>
```

The last solution could be
(But for its conciseness I prefer the second solution)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slc = $('[data-plug="select2"]');
    assignSelect(slc);
    function assignSelect(selectElement) {
        selectElement.each(function(){
            var $this  = $(this),
            plugOp = $.parseJSON($this.attr('data-plug-op'));
            $this.select2(plugOp);
        });
    }   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below  ,

```
function assignSelect(selectElement) {

selectElement.each(function(){

    var $this  = $(this),
        plugOp = $.parseJSON( $this.attr('data-plug-op') );

    /*-- --*/
    $.each(plugOp,function(k,v){

       $this.select2().data('placeholder', plugOp.placeholder).select2({
                    formatNoMatches: function (term) {
                        return 'no match "' + term + '" item';
                    },
                    allowClear: true,
                    containerCssClass : plugOp.containerCssClass,
                    dropdownCssClass: plugOp.dropdownCssClass

        });


    });
    /*-- --*/

});
```

}

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wicutoti/14/edit)

Comment: Thank you, but options are changeable not only placeholder containercssclass and dropdowncssclass. I just gave examples. I want to create plugin options dynamically as key:value in data attribute for each element

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your function to this:

```
function assignSelect(selectElement) {
    selectElement.each(function(){
        var $this  = $(this),
        plugOp = $.parseJSON($this.data('plug-op'));
        $this.select2(plugOp); // select2 accepts object as options, which plugOp is
    });
}
```